# Wifi usb adapter not working/ how to install drivers?

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, kubuntu

I am a new user of Kubuntu. I am a complete layman when it comes to ubuntu.
I use "usb wifi adapter" to connect to the internet. In windows it was a straight forward task but in Kubuntu, it has become a mission impossible for me.

I did search about how to install wifi adapter or how to install its drivers. I have tried every solution but nothing works for me.
(I already have its drivers but dont know how to install them.)

When I use command "lsusb" the following hardware appears.

Bus 002 Device 009: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter

Please help me how do I make it work. Please tell me in a simple way. I don't know any Ubuntu terms. It took me two days to figure out how to open command prompt/Term :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to build this: https://github.com/terence-deng/mt7601u

```
$ sudo -s
# apt-get update && apt-get install -y git wget gcc make build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
# git clone https://github.com/terence-deng/mt7601u
# cd ~/mt7601u && mkdir -p src/mcu/bin && \
wget -c 'http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/mt7601u.bin' \
-O 'src/mcu/bin/MT7601.bin'
# make clean && make all
# ./load.sh
```

Comment: Thank you Jan for your answer. I have tried your solution. First three commands work but the 4th command does not work. When I paste the 4th command i.e. {cd ~/mt7601u && mkdir -p src/mcu/bin && \
wget -c 'http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/mt7601u.bin' \
-O 'src/mcu/bin/MT7601.bin'} the answer comes "No such file or directory". Please help. Thanks

Comment: Try cd after sudo -s